# installing tensorrt in conda env

Tags: conda, tensorrt

I am trying to install tensorrt in conda env and I have the cudatoolkit and cudnn installed in my env through conda navigator.
I have also updated my pip and setuptool
but the get the below error
what should i do?

Error:

````
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting nvidia-tensorrt
  Downloading nvidia-tensorrt-0.0.1.dev5.tar.gz (7.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Zaniar.J\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j1d5secx\nvidia-tensorrt_4052b513fcf14f1c9e44ac829f00ae55\setup.py", line 150, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError(open("ERROR.txt", "r").read())
      RuntimeError:
      ###########################################################################################
      The package you are trying to install is only a placeholder project on PyPI.org repository.
      This package is hosted on NVIDIA Python Package Index.

      This package can be installed as:
      ```
      $ pip install nvidia-pyindex
      $ pip install nvidia-tensorrt
      ```
      ###########################################################################################

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
````

Comment: How are you trying to install it?

Comment: with pip---pip install nvidia-tensorrt

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/quick-start-guide/index.html), and as the error suggests you first have to install:

```
pip install nvidia-pyindex
```

After that  you can do:

```
pip install --upgrade nvidia-tensorrt
```

Comment: I believe the package is `pip install tensorrt --extra-index-url https://pypi.nvidia.com` (version 8.6) and not `nvidia-tensorrt` which is version 99. In other `nvidia-` packages there is a warning: "WARNING: This project is not functional and is a placeholder from NVIDIA." cf https://pypi.org/project/nvidia-cudnn/

Answer (score 0):

Considering you already have a conda environment with Python (3.6 to 3.10) installation and CUDA, you can pip install nvidia-tensorrt Python wheel file through regular pip installation (small note: upgrade your pip to the latest in case any older version might break things `python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools pip`):

```
conda create --name env_3 python=3.9
conda activate env_3
python3 -m pip install --upgrade nvidia-tensorrt
python3 -m pip install nvidia-pyindex
```

You can also check the installation by entering `python3`on cmd line and typing out some python tests:

```
import tensorrt
print(tensorrt.__version__)
assert tensorrt.Builder(tensorrt.Logger())
```

In case you have errors, most precise documentation is the [official](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html#installing-pip) one

Comment: I understand that `python3 -m pip install nvidia-pyindex` shall be issued before the installation of `nvidia-tensort` as this last _extends the default pypi package index with and additional nvidia index_