# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorrt

Tags: pip, tensorrt

When I try installing `tensorrt` on linux using

```
pip3 install nvidia-tensorrt
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorrt
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to install only the Python bindings for TensorRT? In either case, please read [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/quick-start-guide/index.html#install) first.

Please refer to [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html#installing-debian) guide for installing TensorRT on Linux.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade tensorrt
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73703134/installing-tensorrt-in-conda-env) answer may help you, too, if above does not work:

```
pip install nvidia-pyindex
pip install --upgrade nvidia-tensorrt
```

In addition, kindly make sure that you have a supported Python version and platform.

> The tensorrt Python wheel files only support Python versions 3.6 to 3.10 at this time and will not work with other Python versions. Only the Linux operating system and x86_64 CPU architecture is currently supported. These Python wheel files are expected to work on CentOS 7 or newer and Ubuntu 18.04 or newer.

Comment: For me, it was indeed the python version that broke it (too new).

Answer (score 1):

You can install tensorrt by specifying url for installation.

```
pip install --no-cache nvidia-tensorrt --index-url https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
```

or you can try installing tensorrt_libs

```
python3 -m pip install --extra-index-url https://pypi.nvidia.com tensorrt_libs
```

Comment: First line resolved my problem, awesome answer!